# queries with hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a database include eventType and event Tables

```
eventType 

  - id
  - name

event

  - id 
  - name
  - location
  - eventType_id
  - eventSubType_id
```

where eventType_id and eventTypeSubtype_id reference to eventType Table.

What i want to do with hibernate is select all events that have :

- eventType in (2,6)
- and eventSubType in (2,null)

I did :

```
EventCriteria.createCritria("eventType").add(Expression.in("id"),new Long [] {2L,6L});
EventCriteria.createCriteria("eventSubType").add(Expression.in("id", new Long [] {2L,null}));
```

The output not consider the events that have eventype with id (2 or 6) and eventSubType is null, it consider only the events that have eventype with id (2 or 6) and eventSubType is (2). The output must Be both

Thanks

Comment: and what did you try and didn't work?

Comment: Just an advice, leave criteria is ugly, difficult to read and understand, its way better to use HQL since its much readable and very close to SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your eventType numbers are ids...

```
select event 
from Event event
where event.eventType_id in (2,6)
and (eventSubType is null
     or eventSubType = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `eq` instead of `in`...